# NSMutableArray to NSString conversion

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Here is the string from NSMutableArray:

```
(
    (
        "Some String Value"
    )
)
```

This code displays the string value that I want, but however, it displays with the brackets and quotes. How do I remove them?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: It's a string within an array within an array.

Comment: @darshana : please tell me is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is 2D Array:

Something like this:

```
NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"asdf"];
NSArray *arr2=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:arr, nil];
```

You need to go to 2nd level to retrive it as :

```
NSLog(@"=> %@",arr2[0][0]);
NSString *string=arr2[0][0];
```

Comment: Why downvote? Can't you see ( ( and ) ) this is only for nested Array or as we say them 2 Dimentional array.

Answer (score 0):

-(void)repeatArray:(NSArray *)array1 
{

```
static NSMutableString *InsideString; // Better to use global Varaible declared in ViewDidLoad/loadView

NSArray *array = array1; //Its your array

for (int i = 0; i< [array count]; i++) {
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        [self repeatArray:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    } else if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        [InsideString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [array objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
}
```

}